# PHP Scrape external website for favicon

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape any website that a user inputs into a database to get the link of the favicon with PHP.

I am able to scrape a site with this simple code:

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com";
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
```

I can see the entire youtube site from there.  But all I need is to get the favicon link.  I started following [this tuturial](https://gist.github.com/anchetaWern/6150297) to get certain data, but this looks like it only grabs elements in the body?

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com";
$output = file_get_contents($url);
$full_site = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
if(!empty($output)){
    $full_site->loadHTML($output);  
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $full_site_xpath = new DOMXPath($full_site);
    $favicons = $full_site_xpath->query('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
    if($favicons->length > 0){
        foreach($favicons as $favicon){
            echo $favicon->nodeValue;
            echo "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not outputting anything (besides "test").  All of the statements work except the `echo $favicon->nodeValue;`.  Is there anything I can do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That xpath just needs a little adjusting by adding `/@href`.

```
$favicons = $full_site_xpath->query('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]/@href');
```

`$favicon->nodeValue` will then contain what you're expecting.

Comment: Very nice and very easy! Thank you!